# DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") is returning AM time instead of PM time?

Tags: .net, datetime

I'm trying to get the current time via `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")`

However, this is spitting out a time 12 hours off of what we want.

For example:

What it spits out: `11/14/2011 2:24:56 am`

What we want: `11/14/2011 2:24:56 pm`

What noob mistake are we making?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Where is the am/pm marker being added as it is not in your formatting string e.g. 'tt'?

Comment: For some reason what you say the format string produces (`11/14/2011 2:24:56 am`) is very different from what I would expect the format string you posted (`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`) to produce. Are you sure about this?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Use `HH` for 24 hour hours format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Or the `tt` format specifier for the `AM/PM` part:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Take a look at the [custom Date and Time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) documentation.

Comment: I had to use MomentJS just to do that, this saves hell lot of time :)

Answer (score 6):

With C#6.0 you also have a new way of formatting date when using string interpolation e.g.

```
$"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"
```

Can't say its any better, but it is slightly cleaner if including the formatted DateTime in a longer string.

[More about string interpolation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Answer (score 1):

We have to use the DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dddd HH:mm:ss").
We must use Capital HH for 24 hours format that would avoid discrepancies in accurate presentation of date time.

[Must Avoid Mistakes using Date Time in C#](http://seoveerendra.blogspot.com/2023/02/must-avoid-mistakes-using-date-time-in-c.html)